# Drag and swap two containers in blazor

Tags: blazor

How do I drag and swap two child containers, which are in a parent container in the same row in blazor without using any .js code?
[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVgZr.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use flexorder in css